# SQL or Oracle Table structure in Redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I am using node and planning to use redis to store data [data will be in the SQL or oracle table format with many fields like ID, name, City, Marks, etc]. 
Found that we can store only key and value in redis with three data structures [in list, set or sorted set].

Is it possible for me to store like Table name [Key name] : Details 
and values like ID : 1, Name : john, Country:Russia,
ID : 2, Name : Rose , Country:US , etc.

Is there any other data structure apart from list, set and sorted set in redis?

Comment: @sripathiKrishnan : Can you help me related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782844/get-all-fields-and-values-of-hash-key-using-redis-in-node

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  See the docs.

http://redis.io/topics/data-types

Answer (score 0):

You also have the `Hash` data structure...

Database tables are used to store Entities. A loose definition of an Entity is something that has a unique primary key. In Redis, Entities are usually stored using Hash data structure, where columns in the database become fields in the Hash. The primary key is stored in the key of the hash.

Database tables also store non-entities, such as relationships between Entities. For example one-to-many relationship is typically done using a foreign key. In Redis, such relationships can be modeled in Sets, Lists or SortedSets.